DANA IPM motor not working
I have a DANA TM4 IPM 6kw motor and its not running.

The controller that I have is supplying 20A, 20A and 45A (approx) when put in reverse, forward and boost mode respectively.
The motor jitters (oscillates) when throttle input is given and then the shaft does not rotate at all. After a while the motor just gets hot.
The connector for the encoder on the motor has 6 pins (+5v encoder supply, Motor temp sensor, Position feedback A, Position feedback B, Controller I/O ground, Encoder shield ground) and I tried connecting an Arduino to the output pins of the encoder but there is not output. This is the code I tried.
Using analogRead function I read the encoder output but it always showed a value between 200-300 that translates to roughly 1.2V. No change in the value when I rotated the shaft by hand.

What is something that I can try to make the motor work? Is the way that I tried getting data from the encoder correct, or is the encoder faulty?

Did you provide pullup resistors for the encoder phase outputs A and B? Many encoders have open drain or open collector outputs.

Tried with 10k pullup and pulldown resistor (also tried INPUT_PULLUP of arduino), still no output.

What is providing the throttle input? The link to the code is about reading the position of as rotary encoder, so not sure how issue with reading the rotary encoder is linked with the motor "jittering". To help get an answer can the question be edited to include (a) a schematic of all connections for the motor, encoder and Arduino (b) all the code (c) links to the datasheet of the motor and encoder.

Arduino was just used to test if the encoder is working or not, otherwise the motor controller has a connector which connects to the encoder directly. And for throttle input I've tried potentiometric and hall effect throttle pedals. I don't have the datasheet of the motor I got it from a third party vendor.

Could you post the exact Dana motor you have and the attached encoder?  Pictures of your setup would help too.
Can you get an Oscilloscope reading of both of the encoder channels, with and without the arduino connected?
